# Pourquoi « Fou amoureux » et pas « fol amoureux » ?

Tags: adjectifs, adverbes, euphonie

Vu sur Yahoo :

> Fou amoureux d'elle, il a quitté femme et enfant.

Je sais que « fou » devient « fol » lorsque le substantif qui suit dans la phrase commence par une voyelle. « Amoureux » étant un adjectif, cette règle ne s'applique pas à la phrase ci-dessous. Cependant je n'arrive pas à trouver une explication logique.

Pourquoi *(un) fol amour* et *fou amoureux* du point de vue de l'euphonie ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Une recherche sur google de *"le fol amoureux"* renvoie à des emplois très anciens où *fol* est un substantif et *amoureux* un adjectif.  Par contre la même recherche sur "*un fol amoureux*" nous livre quelques exemples contemporains où *fol* est un adjectif et *amoureux* un substantif :

- Le dessinateur SETH (né en 1962), alias Gregory Gallant, est d'abord et avant tout **un fol amoureux** des comics américains.
- le célèbre écrivain Lyonel Trouillot, **un fol amoureux** de l'œuvre de Ferré,…
- **Un fol amoureux** des vins naturels. Un ennemi acharné des vins « pasteurisés »…

La règle que tu énonces dans la question est donc respectée même si on attendrait plutôt *un amoureux fou* dans ces trois exemples vu que l'adjectif *fou* est bien plus souvent postposé au nom qu'il complète.

Dans *fou amoureux*, *fou* est en fait un adverbe.  On pourrait d'ailleurs dire *follement amoureux* sans que le sens ne soit modifié.  On peut donc peut-être reformuler la règle d'emploi de *fol* et dire que si *fou* est substantif ou adverbe, la forme *fol* ne peut pas être utilisée.